# Error on installing angular universal to angular CLI project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I tried this following command to install angular universal

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject my_project_name
```

And also tried this command

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

Both commands executed in root folder of project. And got following error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: foodies@9.3.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@9.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~9.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"9.1.13" from @angular/platform-server@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!   peer @angular/platform-server@"^9.0.6" from @nguniversal/express-engine@9.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine
npm ERR!     @nguniversal/express-engine@"9.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-15T04_09_26_299Z-    debug-0.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fkhUrL\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I couldn't figure out the solution of this error.